# Selenium Webdriver with Java - How to create If statement that incorporates a loop

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

In the test i'm running, I need to find the first record that meets variable targetStatus in a table that can't be filtered or sorted.

I have code that can cycle through each table cell to find the right text that i need to input in to a conditional loop.

Essentially the code looks like this (variables declared earlier and base levels set):

```
List<WebElement> tableCells = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td"));
    int tableGet = 0;
    tableGet = tableGet+5;
    int rowNum = 1;

    String sStatus = tableCells.get(tableGet).getText();
    WebElement rowClick = tableCells.get(tableGet);

if (!sStatus.contentEquals(targetStatus)){
        // Status is not the same so cycle through to the next row
        tableGet = tableGet+6;
        rowNum = rowNum+1;
        sStatus = tableCells.get(tableGet).getText();           
    }else
    {
        rowClick.click();
        // Status has matched and the row has been clicked
    }

    return sStatus;
```

I need the first part of the if to loop through the rows until the status meets and goes down the else route.

For reference, the table in question doesn't have any identifiers other than generic classes on them but has the following structure (to 4 rows):

```
<html>
<body>
<table
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
            <th>Heading 3</th>
            <th>Heading 4</th>
            <th>Heading 5</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Field 1</td>
            <td>Field 2</td>
            <td>Field 3</td>
            <td>Field 4</td>
            <td>Field 5</td>
            <td>Deferred</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Field 1</td>
            <td>Field 2</td>
            <td>Field 3</td>
            <td>Field 4</td>
            <td>Field 5</td>
            <td>Draft</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Field 1</td>
            <td>Field 2</td>
            <td>Field 3</td>
            <td>Field 4</td>
            <td>Field 5</td>
            <td>Draft</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Field 1</td>
            <td>Field 2</td>
            <td>Field 3</td>
            <td>Field 4</td>
            <td>Field 5</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post more details around the scenario and some relevant HTML or better yet a link to the page. It's likely that a locator can be created that will find the text you want in one pass and avoid the loop all together.

Comment: I feel it's a bit harsh to down vote the question. I've provided enough code above.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I do understand their point. You haven't provided the basic information which makes it difficult to answer. I can pretty much guarantee that there is a more efficient way to do this if I only had a link to the page (or at least the relevant HTML) and a clearer description of what you are trying to accomplish. An XPath can be written to find the exact TR that contains the text you are looking for and then click it... no loops. It will be a lot faster, less code, and easier to understand.

Comment: Apologies - i wasn't accusing you of the down vote. I've just seen a lot worse examples up voted that neither have code nor have as clear a request. Politics i guess :)

Comment: Have added a table structure that should hopefully help

Comment: I agree with you on the down/up votes thing. Some people's choice to up/down vote is hard to understand... :) Try not to take it personal. My biggest suggestion to anyone asking a question is make sure you've included everything you think people might need to know to answer the question. I see a lot of questions where assumptions are made, info is left out, and no one other than the asker would know.

Comment: Are all the table values really the same in each cell? Are there really 3 TDs that have the value Field 1, etc.? Are all the Status Values really "Status Value"? I'm guessing they aren't. In that case, if you really can't use sample data from the site, make something up that corresponds to actual data. The reason I say this is because it's going to be a lot harder to find text in a specific 1 of 3 TDs if the text is always the same. How do YOU know which one to click on?

Comment: Also, please explain what you are trying to accomplish in words using the HTML. From what I understand it's something like... I look in the last TD of each row for a given string that indicates the status. Once I find the matching text, I click on the ??? What do you click on? The Status value or one of the fields, etc?

Comment: HI - I've updated the Status field set to be a bit more relevant. At the beginning of my test i'm setting the value that the test is looking for. In the above example this would be either Draft, Approved, or Deferred. The table can change at any point so i need the test to be able to cycle through the values to find the first available record for the determined status (this is the targetStatus variable set above and is a string). once it has found this row, i am able to click on it as a control.

Comment: So if I understand the code you have, you want to search for the TD that contains the first instance of the status and click on it (the TD). Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XPath, you can craft a locator that finds only what you want without the loop. If I understand your scenario correctly, you want to find the first row that contains the desired Status (Draft, Approved, or Deferred) in a TD, and then click on that TD. The function below should do that.

```
public void SelectRecordByStatus(String status)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='" + status + "']")).click();
}
```

and you call it like

```
SelectRecordByStatus("Approved");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and apologies for the delay. When trying this, it was stating that it was unable to identify the element at the status: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //td[.='Draft] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).

Comment: Ah... fixed a typo. I forgot a closing single quote. Try the updated code.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm and is much simpler than the initial solution i was trying to solve the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your 'while' loop should have the condition where it loops until all the rows are exhausted, and then check for each iteration if the 'if' condition is met.

```
while(loop until rows are exhausted){
   if(!sStatus.contentEquals(targetStatus)){
      tableGet = tableGet+6;
      rowNum = rowNum+1;
      sStatus = tableCells.get(tableGet).getText();  
      }
   else if(sStatus.contentEquals(targetStatus)) {
      rowClick.click();
      }
}
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated the code to include how i'm identifying table cells (there are no identifiers within the table so i have to identify just by the xpath). I'm quite new to selenium and not sure how to write the condition where i run out of table cells